# mysql index can not use

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a table ‘t_table1′ include 3 fields :

```
`field1` tinyint(1) unsigned default NULL,
`field2` tinyint(1) unsigned default NULL,
`field3` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default ’0′,
```

and a Index:

```
KEY `t_table1_index1` (`field1`,`field2`,`field3`),
```

When I run this SQL1:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1 AS c WHERE c.field1 = 1 AND c.field2 = 0 AND c.field3 = 0
```

Then is show:

```
Select type: Simple
tyle: All
possible key: t_table1_index1
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
rows: 1042
extra: Using where
```

I think it say that my index useless in this case.

But when I run this SQL2:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1 AS c WHERE c.field1 = 1 AND c.field2 = 1 AND c.field3 = 1
```

it shows:

```
Select type: Simple
tyle: ref
possible key: t_table1_index1
key: t_table1_index1
key_len: 5
ref: const, const, const
rows: 1
extra: Using where
```

This case it used my index.
So please explain for me:

1. why SQL1 can not use index ?
2. with SQL1, how can i edit index or rewrite SQL to performing more quickly ?

Thanks !

Comment: How many rows are in your table? If the index won't narrow down the number of rows returned, the optimizer can choose not to use the index at all.

Comment: my table have 1776 records. SQL1 return 10 records, SQL2 return 0 record. 
Can you explain more clearly ? Why SQL1 not use index and SQL2 use index ?

Comment: Probably because for those values the index is not selective enough (it will return over 1000 rows). The optimizer looks at it and decides that reading the index and then using the results to fetch rows will be _more expensive_ than just doing a full table scan. In the second example, the query will select only 1 row. In that case it's worth the overhead of using the index and then fetching the single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query optimizer uses many data points to decide how to execute a query.  One of those is the *selectivity* of the index. To use an index requires potentially more disk accesses per row returned than a table scan because the engine has to read the index and then fetch the actual row (unless the entire query can be satisfied from the index alone).  As the index becomes less selective (i.e. more rows match the criteria) the efficiency of using that index goes down.  At some point it becomes cheaper to do a full table scan.

In your second example the optimizer was able to ascertain that the values you provided would result in only one row being fetched, so the index lookup was the correct approach.

In the first example, the values were not very selective, with an estimate of 1042 rows being returned out of 1776.  Using the index would result in searching the index, building a list of selected row references and then fetching each row.  With so many rows being selected, to use the index would have resulted in more work than just scanning the entire table lineraly and filtering the rows.